# How do I implement the best fit algorithm in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to make a function to solve the bin packing problem with best fit algorithm, but It doesn't output the results I'm expecting.

Here's what I done so far ..

```
const bestFit = (stringArray, maxWidth) => {
  let results = [[]];

  stringArray.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length); // Sort from big to small

  // ['TailwindCSS', 'Woocommerce', 'typescript', 'three.js', 'threlte', 'svelte', 'Python', 'CSS']
  try {
    stringArray.forEach((str, strIndex) => {
      if (!results[0][0]) {
        results[0].push(str)
      } else {
        const tempArray = [];
        results.forEach((_elm, _idx) => {
          tempArray.push({ index: _idx, data: _elm });
        });
        tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
          return a.data.join().length - b.data.join().length; // From small to big
        })
        for (const [_tx, _obj] of tempArray.entries()) {
          const availableSpace = (_obj.data.join('').length + str.length) <= maxWidth;
          if (availableSpace) {
            results[_obj.index].push(str);
            continue;
          } else {
            if (tempArray[_tx + 1]) {
              continue;
            } else {
              results.push([str]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }


  return results;
}
const technologies = ['svelte', 'typescript', 'threlte', 'three.js', 'TailwindCSS', 'Python', 'Woocommerce', 'CSS'];
const MAX_LENGTH = 20;

const results = bestFit(technologies, MAX_LENGTH);

console.log(results);
  // [
  //   ["TailwindCSS", "three.js",],
  //   ["Woocommerce", "three.js",],
  //   ["typescript", "three.js",],
  //   ["threlte", "svelte", "Python",],
  //   ["svelte", "Python", "CSS",],
  //   ["Python", "CSS",],
  //   ["CSS",],
  // ]
```

There's a lot of duplicates and sorting doesn't work well, there's of example the word `CSS` could be in the first child array, but the function put it in a separate array!
What's wrong here?

Comment: What have you found out during debugging a failing example? Share your findings.

Comment: @MrSmith42 , I wrote the output as a multi-line comment in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw this together, I believe it's what you are looking for.

You should try to break your problem down into smaller parts, individual functions that do one thing each and make sure that they work.

In this case I have a few helper functions, `chooseBinWithMostSpaceLeft` takes the list of bins and figures out which one has the most space left. If no bins have room left, it returns `undefined`.

Then, in the main function we take that bin with the most space left, and make sure the item will actually fit into it. If it does, great, we add the item, otherwise make a new bin.

We also have to make sure the items themselves aren't too big, that's what my filter does, it checks too make sure the strings aren't bigger than the maximum width.

EDIT: I misread the problem definition and gave the worst-fit solution. Here is the best fit, there was also a bug in my `chooseBinWithLeastSpaceLeft` function that would result in undefined being returned in some cases even when there were valid bins.

```
function worstFit(stringArray, maxWidth) {
  const willFit = stringArray.filter((str) => str.length <= maxWidth);

  willFit.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

  const bins = [];

  willFit.forEach((str) => {
    // find the bin with the most space left in it.
    const worstBin = chooseBinWithMostSpaceLeft(bins, maxWidth);

    // make sure that bin is not undefined.
    // make sure the item fits in that bin.
    if (worstBin !== undefined && willBinFit(worstBin, maxWidth, str)) {
      // add the item to the bin.
      worstBin.push(str);
    } else {
      // make a new bin with the item in it.
      bins.push([str]);
    }
  });

  return bins;
}

/**
 * find the bin with the most size left.
 * returns undefined if no bins have size left.
 */
function chooseBinWithMostSpaceLeft(bins, maxWidth) {
  return bins.reduce((max, bin) => {
    const binWidthLeft = getRemainingBinWidth(bin, maxWidth);
    if (max === undefined && binWidthLeft > 0) return bin;
    // this bin has room left, can use it.
    else if (max === undefined && binWidthLeft <= 0) return min;
    // this bin doesn't have room left, cannot use it.
    else if (binWidthLeft <= 0) return max;
    else {
      const maxWidthLeft = getRemainingBinWidth(max, maxWidth);
      if (binWidthLeft > maxWidthLeft) return bin;
      else return max;
    }
  }, undefined); // start undefined, it is possible there are no bins with room left.
}

// Determine how much space the items in the bin are taking up.
function getBinWidth(bin) {
  return bin.reduce((sum, str) => sum + str.length, 0);
}

// Determine how much room the bin has left.
function getRemainingBinWidth(bin, maxWidth) {
  return maxWidth - getBinWidth(bin);
}

// Determine whether or not the item will fit in the bin.
function willBinFit(bin, maxSize, item) {
  return getRemainingBinWidth(bin, maxSize) >= item.length;
}

function bestFit(stringArray, maxWidth) {
  const willFit = stringArray.filter((str) => str.length <= maxWidth);

  willFit.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

  const bins = [];

  willFit.forEach((str) => {
    // find the bin with the most space left in it.

    const bestBin = chooseBinWithLeastSpaceLeft(bins, maxWidth, str);

    // make sure that bin is not undefined.
    // make sure the item fits in that bin.
    if (bestBin !== undefined) {
      // add the item to the bin.
      bestBin.push(str);
    } else {
      // make a new bin with the item in it.
      bins.push([str]);
    }
  });

  return bins;
}

function chooseBinWithLeastSpaceLeft(bins, maxWidth, str) {
  return bins.reduce((min, bin) => {
    const binWidthLeft = getRemainingBinWidth(bin, maxWidth) - str.length;
    if (min === undefined && binWidthLeft >= 0) return bin;
    // this bin has room left, can use it.
    else if (min === undefined && binWidthLeft <= 0) return undefined;
    // this bin doesn't have room left, cannot use it.
    else if (binWidthLeft <= 0) return min;
    else {
      const minWidthLeft = getRemainingBinWidth(min, maxWidth) - str.length;
      if (binWidthLeft < minWidthLeft) return bin;
      else return min;
    }
  }, undefined); // start undefined, it is possible there are no bins with room left.
}

console.log(
  "worst",
  worstFit(
    [
      "TailwindCSS",
      "Woocommerce",
      "typescript",
      "three.js",
      "threlte",
      "svelte",
      "Python",
      "CSS"
    ],
    23
  )
);

console.log(
  "best",
  bestFit(
    [
      "TailwindCSS",
      "Woocommerce",
      "typescript",
      "three.js",
      "threlte",
      "svelte",
      "Python",
      "CSS"
    ],
    23
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried this code, and it works except when I specify a `maxWidth` that equals the length of a big element, for example, when I tried setting `maxWidth` to 11, it didn't output `TailwindCSS` or `Woocommerce` which each one of them equals 11 characters!
`const results = bestFit(["TailwindCSS", "Woocommerce", "typescript", "three.js", "threlte", "svelte", "Python", "CSS"], 11);`
results to `[["typescript",], ["three.js",], ["threlte",], ["svelte", "CSS",], ["Python",],]`

Comment: @a3k please see new code, simple one liner fix. `const willFit = stringArray.filter((str) => str.length < maxWidth);` to `const willFit = stringArray.filter((str) => str.length <= maxWidth);`

Comment: Thanks so much , it is working well now, may I ask what the Big O notation of this function?

Comment: @a3k, if this is for your homework I would prefer not to give you the answer. Take a look at the code and try and figure out what the worst case is as a function of how many strings you send in. (hint: how many times does the function look at each string?)

Comment: Thanks, and no, it's not a homework, but I was just curious :) I'm paying the price of skipping algorithms & data structures courses, I'm a self taught, and I have no excuse but to learn those before going any further.

Comment: @a3k, in that case, its O(n), we loop over elements only once! Upon further reading I'm thinking I realized I made an error. My answer contained the "worst fit" solution, rather than the best fit, I've updated my answer accordingly.